Historical U.S. political party "realignments"?
Robert F. Kennedy, Jr., in his interview with Tucker Carlson (@1:17), says:

There's been a bunch of realignments (about 4 or 5) throughout American history; and I think we're going through one right now, with the Democratic Party and with both political parties really changing in a very dramatic way.

What were these "4 or 5" political party "realignments" in U.S. history?

This is really out of the scope of the site and would be better asked on history as those don't really apply to modern politics anymore.

@JoeW What do you mean by "those"? The "realignments"? How "don't [they] really apply to modern politics anymore"?

@JoeW While it would also be on topic in history, political history is on topic in Politics.SE and it is hard to imagine something more political than the ideology of U.S. political parties. In part, this is because the political history often helps to explain the political present and to explain what in politics is possible but infrequent.

@ohwilleke It can be on topic but it can also not be on topic and in this case I don't see how it is on topic as the realignments don't really apply to modern politics.

The realignments absolutely apply to modern politics and explain how we got the coalitions and policy divisions that we have now, and to how the U.S. political process works. The history is part of 2024 political discourse as quoted above. History is always about the present.

Please don't repost questions... https://history.stackexchange.com/q/76661/14722

@ohwilleke I disagree that the realignments from the 18th and 19th century actually apply anymore and I would say the same for the ones from most of the 20th as well. There has been questions on meta about how far back in history is on topic and I feel that this question isn't on topic. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/cutoff-between-politics-and-history

This is partly opinion-based what constitutes a realignment vs some other kind of change, but see e.g. https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_realignment_in_the_United_States A more sytematic approch but doesn't cover the pre-civil-war era https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/116236/polstudies03.pdf

@JoeW: this can be considered actual through the lens that political theorists don't still quite fully agree what [all] those realignments were. The 2nd link in my previous comment has a discussion. It's not simply a matter of enumerating some historical events.

I don't get to do this much on Politics.SE, but... relevant XKCD

Voting down because this can be answered by trivial research e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_parties_in_the_United_States covers it all

Theoretical Context
Duverger's law states that subject to certain conditions, a political system with single member district plurality vote candidate elections naturally tends towards having two, roughly equal, political parties.
The United States has this kind of political system and has had two major parties for most of its history except brief transition periods and some false starts towards transitions that didn't come to fruition.
(The exception to Duverger's law, which give the U.K. parliament and Canada multiple political parties with a U.S. style-election single member district plurality winner system is that it mandates two dominant political parties in any one geographic area. This has spawned pro- (and sometimes anti-) separatist/autonomy political parties in Northern Ireland, Scotland, and Quebec, for example, but the U.S. has had two main political parties, apart from transitional periods between political party systems, for essentially all of its history.)
In a two party system, the parties form coalitions of people and platforms acceptable to those people, designed to secure majorities prior to the election, rather than by forming coalitions after the election as parliamentary systems with multiple political parties do. Those coalitions and collections of party platform policies constantly change to give each party a shot at a majority coalition, sometimes gradually, and sometimes not so gradually. There are brief periods when one party gains temporary dominance due to major shifts in the political environment and ideologies, but eventually, things settle down back to two major nearly 50-50 political parties again.
The history of the major political parties and the realignment of the political party system in the United States over time is largely a story of the more dramatic and less gradual shifts in those coalitions  and policy leanings in U.S. political history, driven largely by national politics. Many states have spent much longer periods in a dominant period phase, in part, because they are more homogeneous relative to the leading political party divisions at the national level. Federalism in the U.S. has largely prevented each different U.S. state from developing its own political parties that flirt with that 50-50 balance, except by accident when the federal median voter aligns with a state median voter.
A Short History Of U.S. Political Parties
There are up to nine plausible historical events that could constitute a political party re-alignment in the U.S. under the current U.S. Constitution, and I'm not certain which 4-5 were being referred to in this instance. See, in part, here (party divisions in Congress over time).

(not included) The Revolutionary War and Article of Confederation period from 1776 to 1789, prior to the current U.S. Constitution, lacked clear political parties, per se, because the dominant issue was independence from Great Britain and the country was united under the leadership of George Washington, the commander-in-chief of the U.S. military during most of this era.

(arguably) The period without well organized political parties from 1789 to to 1794. This is arguably a pre-political party system rather than a realignment. President George Washington, the hero-leader of the American independence movement and revolutionary war was the President for the first eight years and presided in this time period continuing the unity around independence from Great Britain that prevailed prior to the U.S. Constitution.

(arguably) The Democratic-Republicans party and the Federalist Party from the 1794 election until 1824. This is arguably not a realignment but the starting point of the political party system in the U.S. The Democratic-Republicans favored a weak federal government (and are associated with James Madison and Thomas Jefferson), and the Federalists (most strongly associated with Alexander Hamilton and John Adams) favored a stronger federal government and a national central bank. It emerged as George Washington was on the brink of leaving the political scene removing the unifying factor in the federal government (although the issue of independence from Great Britain, upon which the parties were united, wasn't really fully put to bed until the War of 1812 was concluded).

The replacement of the Democratic-Republicans and the Federalists, with the Jacksonian and Anti-Jackson parties from the 1824 election to 1836. The Jacksonian party was populist and pro-political patronage, the Anti-Jackson party was a "good government" party. Abolition was more a grass roots movement than a political party platform plank of either major political party at this point. The Jacksonian Party was closer to the Democratic-Republican Party, and the Federalist Party was closer to the Anti-Jackson Party, although the coalitions and policy emphasis of the new parties weren't the same.

The replacement of the Jacksonian and Anti-Jackson parties with the Democratic Party and the Whigs from the 1836 election to 1854. The Democratic Party was a Southern pro-slavery party in this time period, while the Whigs were a northern conservative party that tolerated but didn't like slavery. While the coalitions and policy emphasis of the Democratic Party and the Whigs weren't the same, the Democratic Party was basically the successor to the Jacksonian Party and the Whigs were basically the successor to the Anti-Jackson Party.

The creation of the Republican Party in the late 1850s, replacing the Whigs by the 1856 election, with a two year transition period in the 34th Congress following the 1854 election that was muddled and transitional. In this time period, the Republican party was a northern, liberal, abolitionist leaning party (relatively speaking), and the Democratic party was a Southern pro-slavery party. Of course, from 1861-1865, the U.S. Civil War was fought and Republicans dominated Congress and continued to do so during the period after the U.S. Civil War known as Reconstruction, when the formerly Confederate States were reintegrated back in the United States, but post-reconstruction, the Democratic and Republican parties were very similar in ideology and coalitions to the Democratic and Republican Parties that had existed on the eve of the U.S. Civil War. So, while there was a major disruption in the political history of the U.S. at this point, it didn't shuffle the major political parties in the U.S. very much. The Reconstruction period was a "weird" political transition period and dominated by the Republican Party until it ended, nationwide, but didn't have much of a lasting political impact in the former Confederate States. With the slavery issue resolved after the U.S. Civil War and with Reconstruction ended, the Republican party drifted in a conservative direction on economic policy that reached a peak on the eve of the Great Depression (largely ignoring the Jim Crow segregation regime emerging in the South, with an attitude similar to that of the Whigs towards slavery prior to the U.S. Civil War), although its coalition was little changed. In the late 1890s and early 1900s, a third-party progressive movement that tried and largely failed to realign the political party system in the U.S. emerged, favoring temperance, good government, and mostly, more liberal leaning policies, this third-party movement died as the two major parties assimilated key planks of the progressive party platform and then FDR's dominant Democratic party adopted much less incremental economically liberal reforms.

(arguably) The dominant party period during the Great Depression and World War II where the Democratic Party has sustained supermajorities from the 1932 election to 1942. The parties remained the same, but the dominant role of the Democratic Party under President Franklin D. Roosevelt greatly changed the character of the two major parties. Under FDR, the Democratic Party was basically a populist party leaning into being a Western European style Democratic Socialist party, and the Republican party was all but irrelevant at the federal level.

(arguably) The return to a reasonably balanced Republican and Democratic party system in which the Republican party was still northern and urban but had shifted from a liberal party to a center-right party, and the Democratic party which kept strong southern roots (exemplified in the concept of the "Solid South") that was muddied somewhat by the big tent of the dominant party period. This lasted about a decade or two before the process of realignment described in #8 below, eventually took hold in a noticeable way.

If you hear the term "realignment" today, referring to U.S. political parties, the reference is to this process. This is the process by which the Republican Party and the Democratic Party traded ideologies starting around the time of the U.S. Civil Rights movement in the 1950s which had pretty much fully run its course by the mid-twenty-teens. In an interim period during this realignment but before it had fully run its course, the U.S. was basically a three party system with Northern Democrats (economically liberal, socially and militarily liberal), Southern Democrats (economically liberal, socially and militarily conservative), and Republicans (economically, socially, and militarily conservative), as the three de facto parties in terms of voting patterns in the 1980s. President Reagan tried to win over the working class, many of whom were Democrats driven by union membership (he was a union President himself) to the Republican coalition, but was largely unsuccessful in the long run; only when President Trump ran for office did this transition really take hold (and by then, the ranks of private sector blue collar union members was profoundly diminished).


There are 4 of the first 8 that are not arguable. If you include the dominant party period, you get 5. The language of the interview suggests that there were 4-5 realignments prior to the current one (below), so there would be a total of 5-6 realignments over 236 years governed by the current constitution.

The transition from the pre-MAGA until the 2014 election to the post-MAGA political coalition in the Republican Party starting around 2015, in which Democrats and unaffiliated voter identification gained college educated voters, while the Republican party took non-college educated voters from the Democrats and unaffiliated voter identifications. The MAGA Republicans are a populist far-right party with authoritarian and Christian nationalist leanings. The Democratic party is a big tent party (arguably stretched beyond its comfort zone) that includes almost everyone else who wants to affiliate with a political party and tries seriously to hold public office, in its coalition.

As a footnote, historically, in U.S. political history, ideological associations with geographic regions have been more persistent than political party labels (right down to the county level scale in most cases from not long after the initial non-Native American settlement has occurred in a given county). Southern states and rural areas on one hand, and Northern state and urban areas on the other, have been quite stable on their relative ideological leanings on particular classes of issues over time, even as the party labels have changed. Members of Congress from South Carolina have been pitted against members of Congress from Massachusetts, in the same liberal-conservative direction relative to each other on pretty much every major category of political issues, for pretty much all of U.S. history. The various party realignments, and particularly the most recent one, obscure this reality to some extent.
It isn't a perfect stability (e.g., West Virginia left to support the abolitionist cause of the  conservative slave state of Virginia, and now West Virginia is one of the politically most MAGA states in the nation, while Virginia lean blue), but regional ideologies are "unreasonably" persistent in most cases.

Perhaps it seems pedantic, but I'd quibble with calling the FDR Democrats "democratic socialist" - they were closer to social democrats. At no point did the democratic party under FDR endorse socialism or worker control of the means of production. They supported an expanded welfare state, larger state role in the economy, and economic redistribution.

@Anomaly "At no point did the democratic party under FDR endorse socialism or worker control of the means of production." In some sectors FDR did exactly that. A huge share of the intermediate level firms in the agricultural industry and rural America were converted into producer's cooperatives.

Point (9) is not quite completed, is it?  I've seen speculation that if Trump loses (badly) in 2024, conservatives might try to take back the Republican Party.

I'm not sure the UK can be explained solely by regionalism as, for many parliaments, the Lib Dems have been the third largest party & a significant (if minor) force, and they are a national and not a regional party (unlike e.g. the SNP who have only rarely been the third largest party)

@gerrit It is hard to know if a realignment is really competed until the next one starts.

There's far too much "arguably" in this answer, and not nearly enough references to external sources. Seifert's answer is IMHO way better, as it relies on actual sources derived from the work of actual PolySci researchers.

@T.E.D. The "arguably" is because one doesn't know what classification scheme is being used. The Six Party system while used by some historians isn't a very accurate one IMHO.

I would wager that Kennedy was trying to refer to the "Party Systems" that are used by political scientists & historians in order to describe the regional party alignments in various eras of US history.  There are six generally accepted "party systems" that have existed, with some scholars postulating that we are now transitioning the the seventh.

The First Party System (1792–1824) involved the Federalist Party, generally favored by business interests and northern states, particularly New England;  and the Democratic-Republican Party, generally favored by planters and farmers in southern & western states.

The Second Party System (1824–1856) was dominated by the Democratic Party (led by Andrew Jackson) and the Whig Party, with various other anti-Jacksonian parties playing a role as well.  The divide between the parties was largely rural-urban (rural for the Democrats, urban for the whigs) and ethno-religious (Irish & German for the Democrats, English & Scots-Irish for the Whigs).

The Third Party System (1856–1896) pitted the pro-slavery Democrats, with support in the South, against the anti-slavery Republicans, whose support was primarily in the Northeast & West.  This period of course included the Civil War and Reconstruction.

The Fourth Party System (1896–1932) roughly aligns with the Progressive Era.  It had the same parties in the same regions as the previous system, but the dominant issues shifted to concerns stemming from the rapidly industrializing & urbanizing economy.  Reform of the political system (corruption, party politics, direct election of senators, women's suffrage) also featured prominently.

The Fifth Party System (1932–c. 1980) started with the New Deal and the debate over "big government" vs. "small government".  It also featured a significant regional & ideological realignment, as more conservative southerners migrated to the Republican party & liberal northerners migrated to the Democratic party during the civil rights era.  This realignment process happened over several decades, and scholars differ on when this system ended and the next began.

The Sixth Party System (c. 1980–present?) is the present one, with Republicans dominating in surburban & rural areas and Democrats dominating in urban areas.


Some scholars have argued that we are now transitioning (or have transitioned) to a Seventh Party System.

In regards to the 7th, I think we're still in a transition. Both parties are becoming increasingly religious. Its been fascinating to watch a secular pseudo-religion forming in the Democratic party. And the Republican party responding by going more hard Christian.

@DavidS "Both parties are becoming increasingly religious. Its been fascinating to watch a secular pseudo-religion forming in the Democratic party." Umm. . . no. First, secular is not religious. Second, essentially all religious non-Christians have been more or less forced into the arms of the Democratic party regardless of their other political views (e.g. lots of otherwise conservative leaning Muslims, Hindus, and Jews), because Republicans has made it emphatically clear that they aren't welcome there. Ditto for black and Hispanic Christians (many of whom are conservative on many issues).

There is a nice graphic illustration of this scheme in this answer at History.SE of a similar question. https://history.stackexchange.com/a/76514/24010

In a lot of ways this is a better answer to the question than the answer I gave over on the History site. Its far shorter and still covers the necessary ground. Technically it answers what the alignments were, not what the realignments were, but that made for an easier answer, and I suspect the OQ will be fine with it.

Wikipedia's article on the US political parties has a fairly good section on history and the changing party systems. I don't see a need to add to that or to the other answers here.
However, I will suggest the somewhat non-intuitive point that parties are epiphenomenal: things that form out of (and because of) currents and divisions within the populace. Each change in party system reflects a moment when neither party captured the spirit of the times, and so some movement came in and either coopted or supplanted the weaker party with new ideals.
Don't get hung up on the label a party uses; look at the social movements it reflects at given moments in history.

100% agree with the content of this comment, but it feels more like a comment than an answer?

@T.E.D.: This question has been asked and answered a half-dozen times on this site, and the answer is summed up well in that Wikipedia article. I'm not given to excessive repetition, but I thought a little context might be helpful.
